# Can we install chef client and server at custom directory rather than default?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

The default installation of chef-client happens in /opt directory.
I have a requirement where i need to install chef client under /opt/installed_apps directory.

If i am installing it under /opt/installed_apps, it is creating a /opt/chef folder inside /opt/installed_apps and while running the chef-client command, it is throwing an error that "/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby  file or directory not exist".

I tried to set the path of ruby gem i.e /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby in environmental PATH variable but it didn't work.

Please advice do i have to set any specific environment variables for chef-client to work or custom installation of chef client/server is not allowed/recommended.

Thank
Amandeep Singh

Answer (score 0):

Short: you can't, some libraries in the embedded Ruby are statically linked against this directory.

The only workaround I can think of is installing in your destination directory (for mounts or I don't what reason) and then make a symlink to /opt/chef like:

```
 ln -s /opt/chef /opt/installed_apps/opt/chef
```

Going down the path of installing ruby and using gem install sounds overkill and error-prone.

Comment: Overkill and error-prone for sure.  Oh, AlpineLinux says hi, and hopes it'll get an APK  ... one day.

Comment: @user2066657 Feel free to open an issue on github for Chef (and probably for omnibus as well https://github.com/chef/omnibus as it is the packaging system)

Comment: I did, and I'm sure it was there.  But now with the license change - and truckload of money required to get updates like that fix anyway - there's really no need for a fix on my behalf as it's soon to be moot.

Comment: @user2066 we're working on a community distro named cinc, see http://cinc.sh